# After memcpy garbage data is getting printed

Tags: c

I was recently trying to create a function that duplicates the string eg: ip: "apple" count=5, output:"appleappleappleappleapple"

```
char *ch = "apples"
ch = cpy_data(ch, 6, 20);  

char *cpy_data(char *ip_str, int in_len, out_len)
{
    char *c = malloc(out_len);
    memset(c, 0, out_len);
    int rem, n;
    rem = out_len % in_len;
    n = 0;
    while(n < out_len){
        memcpy(&c[n], ip_str, in_len);
        n += in_len;
    }
    if (rem)
        memcpy(&c[n], ip_str, rem);
    printf("%s \n" c);
    return c;
}
OutPut: applesapplesapplesapplesaph�
```

The output len is considerably larger than the expected input as well as some trailing garbage data is getting printed.

Comment: You forgot the NUL terminator (`'\0'`) which `printf("%s` expects

Comment: So I just need to copy '\0' before doing the return?

Comment: Remember, in C, all strings must be *nul-terminated*, otherwise it is simply an array or block of characters in memory. The `"%s"` format specifier (and all C-library `str...` functions) expect a *nul-terminated* string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question contains ~5 syntax errors. It's better to show the code that you used exactly.

Once fixed to be syntactically correct C, your program attempts to write more data to the malloc-allocated block than can fit: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/9c2ce34f

It has been pointed out by Frankie_C in the comments that you may want to reserve room for a final `'\0'`, but this is not sufficient to make the program defined: there is also a logic error in that the program attempts to copy `in_len` more chars as soon as there remains room for one more char: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/3a2b848b

I changed the loop condition to `while (n < out_len - rem) {` just like in Karthick's answer. Now the problem is that the array of chars passed to `printf("%s"` does not end with a final `'\0'`: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/7c1ca032

The final `\'0'` has to be written. Since the destination block was allocated by `malloc` and is not guaranteed to be 0-initialized, it is not enough to leave room for a character at the end. You must also explicitly set the last character to `'\0'`, for instance with:

```
c[out_len] = '\0';
```

Finally, the modified version of your program that does not produce undefined behavior is (https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/dea9e8b2 ):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *cpy_data(char *ip_str, int in_len, int out_len)
{
    char *c = malloc(out_len + 1);
    memset(c, 0, out_len);
    int rem, n;
    rem = out_len % in_len;
    n = 0;
    while(n < out_len - rem){
        memcpy(&c[n], ip_str, in_len);
        n += in_len;
    }
    if (rem)
        memcpy(&c[n], ip_str, rem);
    c[out_len] = '\0';    
    printf("%s \n", c);
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *ch = "apples";
  ch = cpy_data(ch, 6, 20);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your program

1) Your `while` loops makes your memcpy to access the memory beyond what is allocated by you. So make your while look like `while(n < out_len-rem){`

2) strings should always end with `\0`. So your `memcpy` should look like `memcpy(&c[n], ip_str, rem-1);`